# Null Pointer Exception after a 'finally' block

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging, try-catch-finally

I get a NullPointerException at the end of this piece of code :

```
 @Override
    public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK)) {
                handleRegistration(context, intent);
            } else if (action.equals(INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE)) {
                // checks for special messages
                String messageType =
                        intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SPECIAL_MESSAGE);
                if (messageType != null) {
                    if (messageType.equals(VALUE_DELETED_MESSAGES)) {
                        String sTotal =
                                intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOTAL_DELETED);
                        if (sTotal != null) {
                            try {
                                int total = Integer.parseInt(sTotal);
                                Log.v(TAG, "Received deleted messages " +
                                        "notification: " + total);
                                onDeletedMessages(context, total);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "GCM returned invalid number of " +
                                        "deleted messages: " + sTotal);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // application is not using the latest GCM library
                        Log.e(TAG, "Received unknown special message: " +
                                messageType);
                    }
                } else {
                    onMessage(context, intent);
                }
            } else if (action.equals(INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY)) {
                String token = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOKEN);
                if (!TOKEN.equals(token)) {
                    // make sure intent was generated by this class, not by a
                    // malicious app.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Received invalid token: " + token);
                    return;
                }
                // retry last call
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(context)) {
                    GCMRegistrar.internalUnregister(context);
                } else {
                    GCMRegistrar.internalRegister(context, mSenderId);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Release the power lock, so phone can get back to sleep.
            // The lock is reference-counted by default, so multiple
            // messages are ok.

            // If onMessage() needs to spawn a thread or do something else,
            // it should use its own lock.
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                // sanity check for null as this is a public method
                if (sWakeLock != null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Releasing wakelock");
                    if(sWakeLock.isHeld()){
                        sWakeLock.release();
                    }
                } else {
                    // should never happen during normal workflow
                    Log.e(TAG, "Wakelock reference is null");
                }
            }
        } // NullPointerException apparently thrown here
    }
```

This is the LogCat :

```
05-07 12:55:06.775: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(19555): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
05-07 12:55:06.775: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(19555): GCM IntentService class: com.predictoo.whimbee.GCMIntentService
05-07 12:55:06.775: V/GCMBaseIntentService(19555): Acquiring wakelock
05-07 12:55:06.815: D/GCMIntentService(19555): onMessage - context: android.app.Application@41aecd40
05-07 12:55:06.815: V/GCMBaseIntentService(19555): Releasing wakelock
```

This is a screenshot of the error :

[image: error]

After adding a catch block, I got the actual stacktrace of the exception :

```
05-07 14:15:38.216: W/System.err(26532): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
05-07 14:15:38.226: W/System.err(26532):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
05-07 14:15:38.226: W/System.err(26532):    at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:119)
05-07 14:15:38.226: W/System.err(26532):    at com.predictoo.whimbee.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)
05-07 14:15:38.226: W/System.err(26532):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:179)
05-07 14:15:38.226: W/System.err(26532):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
05-07 14:15:38.236: W/System.err(26532):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 14:15:38.236: W/System.err(26532):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 14:15:38.236: W/System.err(26532):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: On which line is it throwing exception ?

Comment: @VKSingla I added a quote on the line throwing the exception. It's one of the last line, before the last bracket.

Comment: The Exception is not actually thrown "after" your finally block. A finally block will always execute, even when an undeclared exception is thrown inside the try block. So the actual exception has occured inside the try block and can be identified by the line number in the stack trace.

Comment: What @NilsH said, which line is line 215?

Comment: The line you are quoting doesn't contain any code. just a bracket. Possibility is you are not getting the correct line at which exception is thrown, or you are running a different file and this file is different.

Comment: Have you initialized the `LOCK` anywhere or is it null ?

Comment: @RomainBraun : I think the source file is out of sync with the class file.
Compile the class again and try running the process would help in identifying the exact line of error.

Comment: @NoobUnChained I checked, the LOCK isn't null.

Comment: @VKSingla I don't understand how I could be running a different file ?

Comment: @Munesh I don't really understand. How would I do that ?

Comment: Just compile your file again and then run. Now print the stacktrace and check the line where exception is thrown.

Comment: @VKSingla I just did. It's still happening on line 215.

Comment: @alex23 Indeed ! I got the actual error. I'm editing my question now.

Comment: `com.predictoo.whimbee.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:63)` `null` is passed to `Log.v()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.

Turned out I had to add a catch block to get the actual StackTrace of the exception.

I found out it was coming from this line :

```
Log.v(ME + ":onMessage extras ", extras.getString("message"));
```

So obviously my extras.getString('message') was null.